# How to style a specific border in bootstrap-tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I built this single table using the bootstrap-tables framework, so its code looks like this:

```
$('#data-table').bootstrapTable({
                        data: arrLeftovers,
                        formatNoMatches: noMatches,
                        columns: [
                            [{
                                title: 'Sobras',
                                colspan: 6,
                                align: 'center'
                            },{
                                title: 'Pass-through',
                                colspan: 5,
                                align: 'center'
                            }],
                            [{
                                field: 'food',
                                align: 'start',
                                title: 'Alimento',
                                sortable: true,
                            }, {
                                field: 't1',
                                align: 'center',
                                formatter: numberFormatter,
                                title: '1° T',
                            },{
                                field: 'tn',
                                align: 'center',
                                formatter: numberFormatter,
                                title: 'TN',
                            }, {
                                field: 't2',
                                align: 'center',
                                formatter: numberFormatter,
                                title: '2° T',
                            }, {
                                field: 't3',
                                align: 'center',
                                formatter: numberFormatter,
                                title: '3° T',
                            }, {
                                field: 'total_leftovers',
                                align: 'center',
                                formatter: numberFormatter,
                                title: 'Total',
                            }, {
                                field: 'through_t1',
                                align: 'center',
                                formatter: numberFormatter,
                                title: '1° T',
                            },{
                                field: 'through_tn',
                                align: 'center',
                                formatter: numberFormatter,
                                title: 'TN',
                            }, {
                                field: 'through_t2',
                                align: 'center',
                                formatter: numberFormatter,
                                title: '2° T',
                            }, {
                                field: 'through_t3',
                                align: 'center',
                                formatter: numberFormatter,
                                title: '3° T',
                            }, {
                                field: 'total_through',
                                align: 'center',
                                formatter: numberFormatter,
                                title: 'Total',
                            }]
                        ]
                    });

                    function noMatches(){
                        return 'Nada cadastrado.';
                    }

                    function numberFormatter(value, row){
                        if(value.toFixed(2) == 0 || value.toFixed(2) == 'NaN'){
                            return ``
                        }else{
                            return value.toFixed(2);
                        }
                    }
```

Look like that, its image of my table:

[My table link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNynm.png)

But, I need to separate "SOBRAS" from "PASS-THROUGH", either with a line or some spacing, can anyone help me?

*I try something like set a class in  in TD of column "Total" in "Sobras", and get the TD closest, but this doesnt work to me. I don't know with dont work because the table do rebuild or something like that.*

This is my array:

```
[
    {
        "food": "Arroz integral reg",
        "t1": 0.224,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.0011200000000000001,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0.224,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Abóbora ",
        "t1": 0.12,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.0006,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0.12,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Radite",
        "t1": 0.12,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.0006,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0.12,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "batata doce rustica",
        "t1": 0.12,
        "t2": 10,
        "t3": 0.434,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.0006,
        "per_capita_2": 0.1,
        "per_capita_3": 0.0041333333333333335,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 10.553999999999998,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "chuchu a parisiense",
        "t1": 0.321,
        "t2": 10,
        "t3": 0.453,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.001605,
        "per_capita_2": 0.1,
        "per_capita_3": 0.004314285714285714,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 10.774,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "creme de tapioca",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": 0,
        "per_capita_3": 0,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Feijão reg",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Almeirao com manga",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "agrião com manga",
        "t1": 0.302,
        "t2": 10,
        "t3": 0.127,
        "tn": null,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": null,
        "per_capita_1": 0.00151,
        "per_capita_2": 0.1,
        "per_capita_3": 0.0012095238095238096,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0.52,
        "total_leftovers": null,
        "total_through": 0.52
    },
    {
        "food": "frango assado",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": 0,
        "per_capita_3": 0,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Aipim reg",
        "t1": 0.251,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.001255,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0.251,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "salada multicor",
        "t1": 0.3,
        "t2": 10,
        "t3": 0.134,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.0015,
        "per_capita_2": 0.1,
        "per_capita_3": 0.0012761904761904763,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 10.434000000000001,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "cenoura conserva",
        "t1": 0.2,
        "t2": 10,
        "t3": 0.423,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.001,
        "per_capita_2": 0.1,
        "per_capita_3": 0.004028571428571428,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 10.623,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Arroz",
        "t1": 0.254,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.00127,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0.12,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0.254,
        "total_through": 0.12
    },
    {
        "food": "feijão",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": 0,
        "per_capita_3": 0,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Viradão Paulista reg",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "arroz integral",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": 0,
        "per_capita_3": 0,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "chicória",
        "t1": 0.2,
        "t2": 10,
        "t3": 0.2,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.001,
        "per_capita_2": 0.1,
        "per_capita_3": 0.0019047619047619048,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 10.399999999999999,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "arroz arroz integral",
        "t1": 0.102,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.0005099999999999999,
        "per_capita_2": 0,
        "per_capita_3": 0,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0.102,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "repolho branco ralado",
        "t1": 0.1,
        "t2": 10,
        "t3": 0.123,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.0005,
        "per_capita_2": 0.1,
        "per_capita_3": 0.0011714285714285713,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 10.222999999999999,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "isca com molho acebolado",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": 0,
        "per_capita_3": 0,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Frango reg",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "bife grelhado",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": 0,
        "per_capita_3": 0,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Mista pronta",
        "t1": 0.2,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.001,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0.2,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Arroz reg",
        "t1": 0.554,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0.0027700000000000003,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0.554,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "melão",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 100,
        "portion_t3": 105,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": 0,
        "per_capita_3": 0,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    },
    {
        "food": "Pepino com casca",
        "t1": 0,
        "t2": 0,
        "t3": 0,
        "tn": 0,
        "portion_t1": 200,
        "portion_t2": 0,
        "portion_t3": 0,
        "portion_tn": 0,
        "per_capita_1": 0,
        "per_capita_2": null,
        "per_capita_3": null,
        "per_capita_tn": null,
        "per_capita": null,
        "through_t1": 0,
        "through_t2": 0,
        "through_t3": 0,
        "through_tn": 0,
        "total_leftovers": 0,
        "total_through": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Please also include the HTML code of your table, it might be that only there we might include the required styling.

Comment: Did you check my answer below? An update would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [column class](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#column-options/class.html) property is what you are looking for.

Change your column definition to include a unique class name for the bordered column:

```
   [{
      title: 'Sobras',
      colspan: 2,
      align: 'center',
      class: 'bordered-right'
    },{
      title: 'Pass-through',
      colspan: 1,
      align: 'center'
    }]
```

And add the CSS code to define the border:

```
.bordered-right {
  border-right: 3px solid black !important;
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/Moonbird-IT/12984).

The `!important` is required to change the border width that is already defined via specific CSS rule to "0 1px" as:

```
.table-bordered > :not(caption) > * > * {
  border-width: 0 1px;
}
```